# Android app (can be rooted) to log SMS sent by other apps

Tags: android, sms

I currently use Bluestacks. There are some apps that tries to send text message for phone number verification. I want to be able to see those text messages so I can send them manually from my phone.

Is it possible to get such logs in Android?

Comment: Not tried, but AFAIR [Tasker](//android.stackexchange.com/tags/tasker/info) is capable of that (amongst many other things it can accomplish). I'm sure for incoming messages, but don't remember the other direction.

Comment: @Izzy I tried it on Bluestacks. They have option for outgoing too but it was not working

Comment: `There are some apps that tries to send text message for phone number verification`, If you are talking about IM applications(WhatsApp, Telegram etc), they are not sending any SMS from your phone to verify the number. Verification characters are generated on their server and send it to your number which you have entered in verification process